# Does “counterpart” mean “équivalent”?

Tags: traduction

It seems a little bit strange, “counterpart” got a meaning of opposite or against. 
When I looked on the internet I found that it means “*homologue*” and “*équivalent*”. Is that correct?

Additionally, is “counterpart” written with “u” or not? I.e., do we write “counterpart” or “conterpart”?

Comment: I think you should avoid using back ticks in your posts. Back ticks are meant for the inline inclusion of code (which is rarely useful here) can mess things in some case — e.g. speech synthesis.

Comment: The second question from your post is off-topic (it’s about english). The correct word is “counterpart”.

Comment: As currently phrased this question is about English.

Answer (score 3):

Here’s an extract<sup>1</sup> from the Oxford Dictionary of English:

> Counterpart (noun) 1. a person or thing that corresponds to or has the same function as another person or thing in a different place or situation: the minister held talks with his French counterpart.

As you can see, there is no notion of opposition. “Counterpart” means, more or less “the same, but in a different context”. The proper translation would is thus indeed “*homologue*” or, in some contexts, “équivalent”.

> [Homologue (A., —*subst.*)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/homologue) Personne ou collectivité remplissant un rôle analogue d'une structure à une autre, d'un pays à un autre.

---

1. The other entry is of little interest here.